# Immutable class design

Tags: java

One of the advice given by Joshua Bloch is that, class should be designed as immutable.

I have the following class

```
public class Dividend {
    public Dividend setDate(SimpleDate date) {
        Dividend dividend = new Dividend(this.getStock(), this.getAmount(), date);
        return dividend;
    }
.....// More to go.
```

For *setDate* method, *this* object will not be modified.

Instead, a clone copy of *this* with its date field being modified will be returned.

**However, by judging from the method name, how does the user will know *this* object will still remain immutable?**

Is there a better naming convention besides *setDate*?

Comment: Does class `Divident` have a `setComment` method that modifies the object? Then it's not immutable.

Comment: If your setComment method is private then only this class is immutable.

Comment: Instead of `setDate`, you can try things like `onDate`/`withDate`/`forDate`, etc.

Comment: I remove setComment in this example to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have setters, your class will look mutable, and users will probably use it the wrong way. They'll probably call it like this:

```
dividend.setDate(myDate);
```

And then be surprised why the `dividend`'s date didn't change. They should have used it like this:

```
newDividend = dividend.setDate(myDate);
```

To make the API more intuitive, it would be better to rename the `setDate` method to something like `copyWith`:

```
newDividend = dividend.copyWith(myDate);
```

Or, if you have many fields and overloading would be confusing, you could call them `copyWithDate` and `copyWithComment`.

Other names are possible too, as stated in the other answers: `derive` (and `deriveWithDate`), or simply `withDate`.

Answer (score 3):

`Font`, for example, has (a) `derive` method(s) which create new font instances derived from the current one.

Comment: agree - I find the derive naming quite intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Many Java libraries I've seen are starting to use `with` as the prefix for 'a copy of this object, *with* the following changes'.

For example:

```
public Dividend withDate() {
   ....
```

which lends itself to

```
Dividend newDividend = oldDividend.withDate(...).withAmount(...).withComment(...);
```

[JSR-310](https://jsr-310.dev.java.net/), for example, follows this pattern (as well as using `plusXxx()` and `minusXxx()` for 'adjuster' objects which take a delta rather than an absolute value, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You should implement your class just like a String class, which has no setters on it. It will be understood that it is immutable if nobody can set anything on it. (maybe you might want to make the setters private or you might just want to set the variables directly from inside your Dividend class)

Answer (score -1):

This function is just a wrapper for the constructor.  Overload the constructor to accept a full dividend object to copy.  Otherwise, you could rename this function getDividend (it definitely isn't a setter).

Answer (score -1):

Since a `Dividend` is being returned, users will probably know it is a new `Dividend` instance. Even then, you might reconsider the name.

Comment: I would assume it was being a fluent interface and returning `this` if I was unaware it was immutable.